# ERROR Creating a new React app with create-react-app | Cannot find module node_modules\react-scripts\package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have the create-react-app globally installed with npm.

When I try to create a new app with command `create-react-app cdc-admin`, this is returned in Git Bash:

```
Creating a new React app in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\estudo\React\app-teste\cdc-admin.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...


Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
{ Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\estudo\React\app-teste\cdc-admin\node_modules\react-scripts\package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at checkNodeVersion (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:514:23)
    at getPackageName.then.then.then.packageName (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:312:7)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting cdc-admin / from C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\estudo\React\app-teste
Done.
```

I've looked everywhere and I did not find the solution.

Comment: Make sure to run cmd as Administrator

Comment: @facundo Ok. I checked.

I'm running cmd as Administrator and error persists.

Comment: Re-Install create-react-app globally and give it a try.

Comment: @nxSolari I re-installed globally create-react-app now, and the error appears:

`Error: Cannot find module 'chalk'`